# How to get terms from a custom taxonomies after WordPress 4.5.0

Tags: taxonomy, terms

I have been developing the shortcodes for which am pulling the terms of custom taxonomies from a plugin. It was working fine prior to WordPress 4.5.0 and now realized it is not working after 4.5.0.

I am pulling those terms in an old method like below.

**Old Method**

```
// Sermon Topics
$prefix_topic_terms= array();
if ( ! empty( $prefix_topic_terms ) ) {
    $prefix_sermon_topic = get_terms('ctc_sermon_topic', 'orderby=name&hide_empty=0');
    foreach ($prefix_sermon_topic as $category) {
        $prefix_topic_terms[$prefix_sermon_topic->slug] = $prefix_sermon_topic->name;
    }
}
```

**New Method that didn't work**

```
// Sermon Topics
$prefix_topic_terms = array();
if ( ! empty( $prefix_topic_terms ) ) {
    $prefix_sermon_topic = get_terms( array(
        'taxonomy' => 'ctc_sermon_topic',
        'hide_empty' => false,
        'orderby' => 'name',
        'hide_empty' => true,
    ));

    foreach ($prefix_sermon_topic as $category) {
        $prefix_topic_terms[$category->slug] = $category->name;
    }
}

var_dump($prefix_topic_terms);
```

Displays Error Invalid Taxonomy error as below

```
object(WP_Error)#2577 (2) {
  ["errors"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["invalid_taxonomy"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(17) "Invalid taxonomy."
     }
  }
  ["error_data"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Edited**
Got success with the following code

```
// Sermon Topics
$prefix_topic_terms = array();
$prefix_sermon_topic = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => 'ctc_sermon_topic',
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'hide_empty' => true,
));
if ( ! empty( $prefix_topic_terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $prefix_topic_terms ) ) {
    foreach($prefix_sermon_topic as $category) {
        $prefix_topic_terms [$category->slug] = $category->name;
    }
}
```

The above code works if i remove the if condition.

Comment: Are you sure that's what your code looks like? `$prefix_sermon_topic` holds the get_terms() return value, but you dump `$prefix_topic_terms` which should be an array. On a side note, you have `hide_empty` twice in your arguments for get_terms().

Comment: even if dump `$prefix_sermon_topic` it shows invalid taxonomy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it fixed as I was checking the variables which are empty and defined as an array. Now converted the code into a function. Hope this is helpful for others

Earlier the condition was wrong. Now I am checking whether the passed variable is a WordPress Error with [is_wp_error](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_wp_error) and checking the taxonomy terms variable is not empty.

```
function sermon_topic() {
    $prefix_terms = array();
    $prefix_postype_taxonomy = get_terms( array(
        'taxonomy' => 'ctc_sermon_topic',
        'orderby' => 'name',
        'hide_empty' => true,
    ));
    if ( ! empty( $prefix_postype_taxonomy ) && ! is_wp_error( $prefix_postype_taxonomy ) ) {
        foreach($prefix_postype_taxonomy as $category) {
            $prefix_terms[$category->slug] = $category->name;
        }
    }
    return $prefix_terms;
}
```

Where I want to pull the terms I use function `sermon_topic();`

Answer (score 1):

OK, wild guess:

```
$prefix_topic_terms= array();
if ( ! empty( $iva_topic_terms ) ) {
```

vs

```
$prefix_topic_terms = array();
if ( ! empty( $prefix_topic_terms ) ) {
```

You've changed the variable that is checked for emptiness in the new code. That code will never query get_terms for that taxonomy, because `$prefix_topic_terms` will not be empty.
The Error-object you are receiving is probably unrelated from an earlier call to get_terms.

Comment: I tried that but still no luck. But I'm posting an answer again